# Can not Push to github repository form local repository

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push my local project ot my remote repository.
but while i put the `$git push -u origin master`
its not working [image]

Its stuck here for long time.

what i am missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. add remote `$git remote add origin <Your remote repository>` and create branch `$git branch -m master`
2. you must add your files `$git add .` then
3. push to te remote repository `$git push -u origin master`

Answer (score 2):

a workaround i tend to use is going to a difrent folder and do

```
git clone (url here)
```

then copy the projct files to the folder it made
then add the files with

```
git add (files)
```

and commtit with

```
git commit -m "message"
```

and push with

```
git push -f
```

(idk why the -f but  a frend of mine told me to do it so ive done i scince)

Answer (score 1):

1. add remote and create branch
2. you must add your files `$git add .` then
3. push to te remote repository